When the width of the column in the DataGrid is not enough, how to set it to hide the characters at the beginning of the text?
I am using DataGridView in C#/.NET 6.0/WinForms. Is there a way to change the direction of hiding the text when the column width is not enough? I want to hide the text from the beginning (left) when the column width is less than the text width. For example: For "ABCDEFG", I want to display "...DEFG" instead of "ABCD...". I have set the text alignment to "middle-right", but it doesn't work.
Is the only way to add a "CellPainting" event to calculate the text and then cover the original text?

Related: label, custom drawing. datagridview, should be more...

@sdrest, did the solution I suggested in the answer solve your need?

"CellFormatting" event handler can be used to trim the text inside grid cells from the left side.
"WrapMode" and "Padding" should also be set for the columns (similar to what is done in the "SetDataGridViewColumnStyle" method of the code below)
As follows:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillDataGridView();
        SetDataGridViewColumnStyle();
    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            string ValueText = GetStringFromNullableObject(e.Value);
            e.Value = GetLeftSideTrimmedTextForDataGridView(e.ColumnIndex, ValueText, (DataGridView)sender);
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
    private static string GetLeftSideTrimmedTextForDataGridView(int ColumnIndex, string ValueText, DataGridView TheGridView)
    {
        const string ThreeDots = "...";
        ValueText = ValueText.Trim();

        var WidthOfText = GetTextWidth(ValueText, TheGridView);
        var WidthOfThreeDots = GetTextWidth(ThreeDots, TheGridView);
        int WidthOfColumn = TheGridView.Columns[ColumnIndex].Width;
        if (WidthOfText < WidthOfColumn)
            return ValueText;
        else
        {
            var LeftSideTrimmedText = "";
            var ListOfCharacters = ValueText.ToList();
            ListOfCharacters.Reverse();
            var ListOfReverseCharacters = ListOfCharacters;
            var LastCharacter = ListOfReverseCharacters.First();
            var ListOfReverseCharacterWidths = ListOfReverseCharacters
                .Select(ch => GetTextWidth(ch.ToString(), TheGridView))
                .ToList();
            int WidthOfLastCharacter = ListOfReverseCharacterWidths.First();
            if (WidthOfLastCharacter + WidthOfThreeDots > WidthOfColumn)
                return LastCharacter.ToString();
            int CalculatedTextWidth = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ListOfReverseCharacters.Count; i++)
            {
                CalculatedTextWidth += ListOfReverseCharacterWidths[i];
                if (CalculatedTextWidth < WidthOfColumn)
                    LeftSideTrimmedText = ListOfReverseCharacters[i] + LeftSideTrimmedText;
                else
                    return ThreeDots + LeftSideTrimmedText;
            }
        }
        return ValueText;
    }
    private void FillDataGridView()
    {
        var data = new System.Data.DataTable();
        data.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(int));
        data.Columns.Add("Col4", typeof(int));
        data.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFG", 0123456789, 0123456789 });
        data.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFG", 0123456789, 0123456789 });
        data.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFG", 0123456789, 0123456789 });
        data.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFG", 0123456789, 0123456789 });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
    private void SetDataGridViewColumnStyle()
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 40;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 55;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            column.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            column.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0);
        }
    }
    private string GetStringFromNullableObject(object? Value)
    {
        return GetTrimText(Value?.ToString()) ?? "";
    }
    private string GetTrimText(string? Value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value) ? "" : Value.Trim();
    }
    private static readonly Graphics _graphics = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
    private static int GetTextWidth(string Text, Control TheControl)
    {
        var TheFont = GetFontWithNewGraphicUnit(TheControl.Font, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        return (int)_graphics.MeasureString(Text, TheFont).Width;
    }
    private static Font GetFontWithNewGraphicUnit(Font BaseFont, GraphicsUnit NewGraphicsUnit)
    {
        return new Font(BaseFont.FontFamily, BaseFont.Size, BaseFont.Style, NewGraphicsUnit);
    }
}

The output of the program is as follows:

